# l'Hopital's rule for 2 variables to compute Jacobian matrix

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits, multivariable-calculus, jacobian, steady-state

I have a system of three ODEs and I have computed the Jacobian matrix.
One of the steady states is `(0,0,0)` and I am trying to linearize the system around this steady state.
In the Jacobian matrix two of the terms are of the form $cx^2\over cx+y$ and $z\over y$.Here, $x,y,z$ are the variables of the system and $c$ is a known constant.

But when substituting x=0,y=0 and z=0 to the above terms it will be $0\over 0$.

So, in this case, can I use L'hospital rule for 2 variables to compute the Jacobian around that steady state?

That is I want to find
$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}{ cx^2\over cx+y}$ and $\lim_{(z,y)\to (0,0)} {z\over y}$.

I referred to the article on [l'Hopital's rule for multi variable functions](https://arxiv.org/abs/1403.3006)  and with what it says in the article I could not find the limit of
$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}{ cx^2\over cx+y}$ and the limit of $\lim_{(z,y)\to (0,0)} {z\over y}$ does not exist.

Can someone please let me know a method to evaluate the two terms around the steady state.

Comment: Just checking:  Are you saying the Jacobian matrix contains three terms of the two forms or that it has three eigenvalues of the two forms?  (Which could potentially be the same thing, depending on details you haven't shared.)

Comment: @clarkson If the partial derivatives are of such a kind as you describe, then clearly the RHS is not $C^1$ at the origin.  The linearization method can be applied under some conditions weaker than $C^1$, but you have (at least) to check if the RHS is differentiable at the origin (by definition, I think).  What is your system?

Comment: @EricTowers The Jacobian is a 3*3 matrix and J(1,1) term is $cx^2\over cx+y$ and J(2,3) term is $z\over y$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With any limitaton in the domain the two limit doesn't exist, indeed simply note that for $t\to 0$

- $x=0 \quad y=t \implies {cx^2\over cx+y}=0$
- $x=t \quad y=-ct+t^2 \implies {cx^2\over cx+y}=\frac{ct^2}{ct-ct+t^2}=c$

and

- $z=0 \quad y=t \implies \frac z y = 0$
- $z=t \quad y=t \implies \frac z y = 1$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you please explain what this $t$ is

Comment: It' a parametr which tends to zero, it represents a parametrization of $(x,y,z)\to (0,0,0)$ once we find different paths with different limits then we say that the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: So, in this case isn't there any other way that I can use to linearize the system around  (0,0,0)

Comment: This expression have no limit at 0 and are also unbounded, indeed in some trajectories they tends to $\infty$ let try with $z=t$ $y=t^2$ in the second and $x=t$ $y=-ct+t^3$ in the first.

Comment: @clarkson I repeat: Please show your system!

Comment: @clarkson Yes it could be useful take a look to the original problem, you could open a new OP on that